# Output MQTT data into a Node-Red graph

Tags: node.js, graph, mqtt, dashboard, node-red

I am currently using an MQTT client that is linked with some Arduino code that produces numerical outputs at a 2 second interval. This is further linked to a NodeRed flow where it reads the input passed through the broker, and outputs it as a payload message on the dashboard. I am wanting to produce a graph node that is connected to the MQTT subscriber and shows real time data in the UI. I attempted this in the way shown in the example image as I wanted to still see the information in the dashboard, but I could not get a proper graph to appear. Could anyone help me with how I could do this?

[image: Picture of my current flow]

Answer (score 1):

To get the chart node to work properly you need to feed it just the numerical value.

Your MQTT messages are actually a string as follows `Temperature = -70.06660 degrees` so you will need to extract the number from the string.

The quickest way to do this is probably to insert a function node between the MQTT-in node and the chart node.

In the function node add the following code:

```
var parts = msg.payload.split(" ");
msg.payload = parseFloat(parts[2]);
return msg;
```

This should now just feed the numerical part to the chart node.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the prompt response. I have applied that to the function node and that has updated in the payload accordingly, however I cannot seem to get an output in the UI. Once accessing it after deploying the flow, the UI is empty. Could you please provide any further assistance?

Comment: You need to edit the question to add a lot more detail about how you have configured the Dashboard-UI nodes