# Grafana has a problem with "string", needs "float" DHT22-ESP32-Mosquitto-NodeRED-InfluxDB-Grafana

Tags: mqtt, grafana, influxdb, node-red, raspberry-pi4

I started setting up the above stack on my **Pi 4B running Bullseye64**. I mainly used this tutorial:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-mqtt-publish-dht11-dht22-arduino/
However, the instructions stop short of explaining how to display the data in Grafana. When I try a data query in **Grafana v8.3.6** the Grafana query editor returns:

*“InfluxDB Error: unsupported mean iterator type: query.stringInterruptIterator”*

Here is the code from the ESP32 that publishes to **Mosquitto V2.0.11:**

```
uint16_t packetIdPub1 = mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_TEMP, 1, true, String(temp).c_str());
uint16_t packetIdPub2 = mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HUM, 1, true, String(hum).c_str());
```

That appears in the Arduino serial monitor as:

```
Connected to MQTT.
Session present: 0
Publishing on topic esp32/dht/temperature at QoS 1, packetId: 1Message: 68.36
Publishing on topic esp32/dht/humidity at QoS 1, packetId 2: Message: 62.90
Publish acknowledged. packetId: 1
Publish acknowledged. packetId: 2*
```

Mosquito passes it on to **Node-RED V2.2.1** via the MQTT input node and the IfluxDB output node,**(InfluxDb V1.8.10)** which debugs as:

```
2/17/2022, 10:03:50 AM node: ebfbf6e2aea5407d
esp32/dht/temperature : msg.payload : string[5]  "68.36"*
```

When I try a data query in Grafana it returns:

*“InfluxDB Error: unsupported mean iterator type: strong textquery.stringInterruptIterator”*

which, to my understanding means that Grafana is not able to graph the format **“string”** and instead requires format **“float”**

If I change the Grafana query in the **SELECT** field drop down, submenu **AGGREGATORS** from **"median"** to **"count"** I can see the DB entries in a table, so I know data is being written.

My question is,(assuming my understanding is correct...) How do I go about changing the data format from string to float before it is written to InfluxDB? Perhaps I need to add Telegraf between Node-red and InfluxDB?

Comment: Probably best to convert the message to a number before writing to the database (you can do this in Node-Red). MQTT messages are raw bytes; to parse you can use `Number(payload)` /`parseFloat(payload)`; you could do this in a [script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60830481/11810946) or use a [change node](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/nodes#change).